# Difference between map and list iterators in python3

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

I ran into unexpected behaviour when working with map and list iterators in python3. In this MWE I first generate a map of maps. Then, I want the first element of each map in one list, and the remaining parts in the original map:

```
# s will be be a map of maps
s=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
s=map(lambda l: map(lambda t:t,l),s)

# uncomment to obtain desired output
# s = list(s) # s is now a list of maps

s1 = map(next,s)

print(list(s1))
print(list(map(list,s)))
```

Running the MWE as is in python 3.4.2 yields the expected output for s1:

```
s1 = ([1,4]),
```

but the empty list [] for s. Uncommenting the marked line yields the correct output, s1 as above, but with the expected output for s as well:

```
s=[[2,3],[5,6]].
```

The docs say that map expects an iterable. To this day, I saw no difference between map and list iterators. Could someone explain this behaviour?

PS: Curiously enough, if I uncomment the first print statement, the initial state of s is printed. So it could also be that this behaviour has something to do with a kind of lazy(?) evaluation of maps?

Comment: `list()` is not an iterator.

Comment: You exhausted the `s` map by iterating over it via `s1`. I'm not sure why you think `list()` has anything to do with this.

Comment: Yes, I guess that the bottom line is that an iterator is not to be confused with an iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `map()` is an iterator; you can only iterate over it *once*. You could get individual elements with `next()` for example, but once you run out of items you cannot get any more values.

I've given your objects a few easier-to-remember names:

```
>>> s = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> map_of_maps = map(lambda l: map(lambda t: t, l), s)
>>> first_elements = map(next, map_of_maps)
```

Iterating over `first_elements` here will in turn iterate over `map_of_maps`. You can only do so *once*, so once we run out of elements *any further iteration* will fail:

```
>>> next(first_elements)
1
>>> next(first_elements)
4
>>> next(first_elements)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

`list()` does exactly the same thing; it takes an iterable argument, and will iterate over that object to create a new list object from the results. But if you give it a `map()` that is *already exhausted*, there is nothing to copy into the new list anymore. As such, you get an empty result:

```
>>> list(first_elements)
[]
```

You need to recreate the `map()` from scratch:

```
>>> map_of_maps = map(lambda l: map(lambda t: t, l), s)
>>> first_elements = map(next, map_of_maps)
>>> list(first_elements)
[1, 4]
>>> list(first_elements)
[]
```

Note that a *second* `list()` call on the `map()` object resulted in an empty list object, once again.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider that I exhausted the map iterator during the first operation. I guess my frequent use of haskell (where a map over a list returns a list) made me not see this.

Could you comment on the execution order of the mappings, i.e. why map_of_maps is not exhausted when I do not evaluate (print) first_elements?

Comment: @SerJothanChanes: in Python 2, `map()` used to return a list too, but in Python 3 the built-in tools have been converted to iterators; more memory efficient that way.