# Syntax error with Python birthday code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to learn to use this simple birthday one-liner in Python (3.6.5) but am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax, can someone help me figure out where I've gone wrong:

```
print map(lambda x: "Happy Birthday to " + ("you" if x != 2 else "dear Name"),range(4))
```

Thanks!

Comment: if it's python3, add brackets to `print()`

Comment: @OmarEinea and wrap in `list` since `map` is an iterator in 3.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've tagged this as python 3.x. This is python 2.x code. You need

```
print(list(map(lambda x: "Happy Birthday to " + ("you" if x != 2 else "dear Name"),
               range(4))))
```

since `print` is a function, not a statement in python 3. Also `map` returned a `list` in python 2 but [now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an [iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583304/difference-between-map-and-list-iterators-in-python3) which needs to be wrapped in `list` in order to print the values.

---

This is also slightly old-style python, a modern way of writing this would be

```
print(["happy birthday to {}".format('you' if x != 2 else 'dear name') for x in range(4)])
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code fails on python 3.x as already been answered by @FHTMitchell answer, that said, here's a simpler way to achieve what you want in both python2.x/3.x:

```
print(["Happy Birthday to {}".format("you" if x!=2 else "dear Name") for x in range(4)])
```

There is a lot of ways to achieve this task, few more examples:

- `lst = ["Happy Birthday to you"]*4; lst[1] = lst[1].replace("you", "dear Name"); print(lst)`
- `s1 = "Happy Birthday to you"; print([s1,s1.replace("you", "dear Name"),s1,s1])`

But if you ask me, my favourite one, even if not a oneliner, would be doing something like this:

```
import textwrap

song = textwrap.dedent("""\
    Happy Birthday to you
    Happy Birthday to dear Name
    Happy Birthday to you
    Happy Birthday to you
""")

print(song.splitlines())
```

Comment: beat you to it ;)

Comment: posted at the same time than you, meh... giving you +1 for being that fast ;D

Comment: Na the best one liner would be: `print([f'Happy birth to {placeholder}' for placeholder in ['you', 'you', 'dear name', 'you']])` its actually one line :P

Comment: Not an expert on English songs... but wouldn't be Happy birthday instead Happy birth? :D

Comment: [The song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_Birthday_to_You#Lyrics).

Answer (score 2):

*Since we're playing lets find different ways to skin a cat.*

```
placeholders = ['to you'] * 4
placeholders[2] = 'dear name'  # placeholders.insert(2, 'dear name')
print([f'Happy birth {placeholder}' for placeholder in placeholders])
```

ps. I don't like lambdas, they're slow.

---

On another note, thanks @FHTMitchell, I've always known `list.insert()` was slow but i had no idea it was SOO slow.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('a += ["something"]', setup='a = ["thing"]')
0.07153259999904549
>>> timeit.timeit('a[0] = "something"', setup='a = ["thing"]')
0.03036419999989448
>>> timeit.timeit('a.insert(0, "something")', setup='a = ["thing"]')
264.89795089999825
```

Holy smokes!

Comment: If you don't like lambda because it's slow, definitely don't use `list.insert`!

Comment: Your code won't be python2.x compatible... and the song says happy birthday, ie: [http://www.1happybirthday.com/traditional_birthday_lyrics.php](http://www.1happybirthday.com/traditional_birthday_lyrics.php) :'D

Comment: @BPL OP said 3.6.5 -- thats what I use, as far as im concerned, python without f-strings is beneath me, and i refuse to acknowledge its existence. Python was born at 3.6 :P   edit: i fixed the song !!! :P

Comment: @Javier Buzzi Haha, fair enough, I hadn't seen the python3-x tag ;) , +1

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import  sleep
def start():
    name="Birthday person"
    print("\t\ti i i")
    sleep(1)
    print("\t\ti i i")
    sleep(1)
    print("\t\ti i i")
    sleep(1)
    print("\t :------------------:")
    sleep(1)
    print("\t ▐█░█▌█▀▀█ █▀▀█ █▀▀█ █▌▄█")
    sleep(1)
    print("\t ▐█▀█▌█▄▄█ █▄▄█ █▄▄█ █▄██")
    sleep(1)
    print('\t ▐█░█▌█▌▐█ █▌░░ █▌░░ ░██')
    sleep(1)
    print('────────???.•°”˜˜”°•.???')
    sleep(1)
    print('▀██▀▀▄──???.•°”˜˜”°•.???')
    sleep(1)
    print('─██▄▀▄──???.•°”˜˜”°•.???')
    sleep(1)
    print('─██───█─▄──────▄──█───')
    sleep(1)
    print('─██───█─▄─▄─▄─▄█▄─█─▄─')
    sleep(1)
    print('▄██▄▄▀──█─█▀───█──█▀─█')
    sleep(1)
    print('────────█─█────█──█──█')
    sleep(1)
    print('██████║░░▄▄▄▄║▄▄║░▄║♥')
    sleep(1)
    print('███║░██║██║░█║██║░█║♥')
    sleep(1)
    print('███║░██║██║░█║██║░█║♥')
    sleep(1)
    print('███║░██║▀█▄▀█║▀█▄▀█║♥')
    sleep(1)
    print('███║░██║░░░░░░▄░░░█║♥')
    sleep(1)
    print('██████║░░░░░░░▀███▀')
    sleep(1)
    print('')
    sleep(1)
    print('')
    sleep(1)
    print('')


    sleep(2)
    print("A message for you.....")
    sleep(4)
    print("\tMAY GOD BLESS YOU AND YOUR FAMILY\n ALWAYS BE HAPPY AND GOOD HEALTH")
    sleep(5)
    print("one second......")
    print()
    sleep(.3)
    print('────▀██████─────▀─────────────█')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─────▌█───▀─█▄▀─█─▄▀▄─█▄▀█─▄▀▀█─▄▀▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─────▌███───█───█─█▀▀─█──█─█─▄█─▀▀█')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─────▌█─────▀───▀──▀▀─▀──▀──▀─▀─▀▀▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('────▄██▄───█──█─────────────────────')
    sleep(.3)
    print('──────────▀█▀─█▄▀▄─▄▀▄')
    sleep(.3)
    print('───────────█──█──█─█▀▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('───────────▀──▀──▀──▀▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('──▄▄─▄▄──────▀██▀▀▄───────────█')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─█░█████──────▌█▄▀▄──▄▀▄─▄▀▀─▀█▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─▀█░███▀──────▌█───█─█▀▀─▀▀█──█')
    sleep(.3)
    print('───▀█▀────────▌█───█──▀▀─▀▀▀──▀')
    sleep(.3)
    print('─────────────▄██▄▄▀')

a=input("1.Type : 'MJ' \n 2.PRESS 'ENTER' \n (ELSE TYPE 'QUIT' TO QUIT)\n\n:" )
if (a == 'MJ'):
    start()
else:
    print("TAKE CARE BYE!")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!